# Tags [windows-phone-7.1] and [windows-phone-mango] are synonymous

Tags: support, status-completed, stack-overflow, retag-request

Not quite sure on the process (first time on meta) but the tags [windows-phone-7.1](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1) and [windows-phone-mango](/questions/tagged/windows-phone-mango) are synonymous.

Comment: what if windows-phone-7-mango was used?

Comment: Mango is the Microsoft code name for 7.1 I don't have any strong feelings on which is correct (although I think I prefer 7.1), having both tags is redundant

Comment: Added tag synonym for [windows-phone-mango] --> [windows-phone-7.1]

Comment: Windows Phone "codename Mango" is not guaranteed to be 7.1. It may end up being 7.5 or even something else. I suspect we may have been better having these synonyms the other way round. Especially if we end up making `w-p-7.1` a synonym of `w-p-7.5`.

Comment: I will go for windows-phone-mango as that is what everyone is talking about at the moment and hence most likely to be searched for

Comment: The whole Mango vs 7.1 vs 7.5 thing is an issue. It's looking like the codename is and will be Mango, MS tend to forget about codenames pretty quickly after a release. The code build is 7.1 and I don't expect this to chage (although it might) but it looks like the OS migth well be marketed as 7.5 (thanks MS...)