# Windows Phone "codename Mango" and version numbers

Tags: discussion, tags

Sorry if this is a very focused question (tag-wise) but the `windows-phone-7*` tags are where I spend my time.

Sometime in the last 24 hours, someone (I think [user 149573](https://stackoverflow.com/users/149573/otaku)) retagged almost all the the questions tagged [windows-phone-7.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.1) to [windows-phone-7.5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/windows-phone-7.5).

This is presumably in response to the "7.1 beta refresh" which was released yesterday.
To further confiuse things the update reports itself as the RC but it isn't. The RC isn't being made available until August. (And I hope we don't have a similar [re-]tagging issue then!)

In all development documentation "Mango" is referred to as `7.1` but with the disclaimer that this may not be the final version number when it is publically released.
There have been a couple of marketing references (but nothing official) to `7.5` and it has been *assummed* that these will be the same thing.

Please note that previously (as per [Tags [windows-phone-7.1] and [windows-phone-mango] are synonymous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/96033/tags-windows-phone-7-1-and-windows-phone-mango-are-synonymous)) questions tagged "windows-phone-mango" were retagged to "windows-phone-7.1"

I propose reverting the use of `7.5` to use `7.1` as `7.5` doesn't have any official meaning (yet?). If it later (v mango +1?) comes to mean something else it could be misleading.
Questions tagged as `7.1` when asked and relating to beta issues could cause confusion if they are fixed in the release version (7.5?) but all questions are grouped by tag.

If someone really wanted we could create a `windows-phone-7.1-beta-refresh` tag for specific issues but I suspect that keeping these with the `7.1` questiosn will be fine.
If the final release has a different version number (7.5?) then all will be fine. If not, then existing questions could be retagged to `windows-phone-7.1-beta`.

The tag wiki's for both tags (7.1 & 7.5) are both out of date but it makes sense to

I'm keen to avoid a retag war and want to understand if similar things have come up before? (and if so what was done?)
Are there other areas/subjects/topics where specific tags have been created for every version number?

Comment: The official name is **Windows Phone 7.5**. See http://windowsteamblog.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2011/07/26/windows-phone-mango-released-to-manufacturing.aspx in the comments. Rolling all the tags to the new name as 7.1 is only related to the firmware, not the official name.

Comment: All of the tags have been changed back now to the correct one - windows-phone-7.5. Thanks for the zealousness around Windows Phone. 7.1 was an unofficial number for "Mango". The tag could have also been called "windows-phone-mango" (which was indeed used by some early on). The official name of the OS is 7.5 (RTM'd version). With just over 50 questions, it's better to make the change now instead to continue to propogate an incorrect versioning convention. If questions are related to this specific version of the OS, this tag should be used. Otherwise, the generic "windows-phone-7" can be used.

Comment: @Otaku Whe it's released it **WILL** be called 7.5. Right now it's 7.1. Many of the questions you've retagged are specific to issues in the 7.1 timeframe and have since been fixed by beta 2 refresh. They therefore have no relevance under 7.5. Many of the questions you've reagged even specifically refer to specific versions of the beta or include 7.1 in the title of the question. Your retags only serve to group beta issues in with any possible future RTM questions.

Comment: @Otaku If using an SDK which identifies itself as being version 7.1 and there is a question specific to that version of the SDK it should be tagged as that version NOT with the version number of a future version of the SDK. Yes multiple tags can be used to provide additional clarification. More questions have been asked and originally tagged as 7.1 since you started your campaign of retagging so people expect to use the 7.1 tag. If need be, at some future point 7.1 could be made a synonym of 7.5 but let's not second guess the future.

Comment: If you are specifically referring to beta features that do not occur in the RTM'd OS version, you may want to create a tag called "windows-phone-mango-beta" and tag those questions therewith. 7.1 was as much a working name as Mango was - in fact, Mango is far more common. It's clear this is a sensitive issue for you though - to the point where I'm starting to think you created the 7.1 tag and somehow want a Taxonomist badge for that. If is what you're after in your retagging campaign, please go ahead and roll back all the tags to receive your Taxonomist badge.

Comment: Windows Phone Mango has been released. The OS calls itself 7.5, but its SDK calls itself 7.1. Yay consistency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Version specific tags should never be changed when versions change.

The reason we have version specific tags is so that people can understand that a question contains a version specific problem.

If a problem isn't specific to a specific version, it shouldn't have the version specific tag.

If it is, then it should have the tag, and that tag shouldn't be changed.

Comment: the problem here is that people are changing their minds about the name of the version. Anyway, there is no 7.5 yet so it's silly to even have a tag for it, much less to edit things with the 7.1 tag to use the silly 7.5 tag.

Comment: good call. rolling them all back.

Comment: @Kate Gregory: Please see comments above.